# Applet size being rendered is smaller in browser

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, java-web-start

I have created an applet which runs fine when I run it through net beans. I am using Web Start to run the applet on browser. The applet is working fine on browser but the size of the applet is very small and not according to the proportions I set(normal my applet is 200X500 whereas in browser it is 300X300).

How to set the size of the applet in the browser?

I tried editing the `.jnlp` file also but even that didn't work.

The JNLP File is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>GatorMessenger</title>
    <vendor>pratiksomanagoudar</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>GatorMessenger</description>
    <description kind="short">GatorMessenger</description>
</information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se java-vm-args="-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy" version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="GatorMessenger.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swingx-beaninfo-1.6.4.jar"/>
</resources>
<applet-desc height="500" 
main-class="gatormessenger.GatorMessenger" name="GatorMessenger"    width="400">
</applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code you use to embed the applet into the html?

Comment: Once you have displayed the HTML as advised by @fmodos and fixing the problems for FF, consider using the advice offered on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474623/418556) to deploy the applet using `deployJava.js`.