# Java Applet errors on Web Hosting site

Tags: java, html, applet, classnotfoundexception, japplet

I am having problems trying to run my applet file when I upload it on my website. It keeps giving me errors, but works perfectly fine on my computer. I am using NetBeans to create my Applets and I used the `<Applet>` tag, since I remember using it and it worked. But NetBeans did state a warning message stating that the `<Applet>` tag has been deprecated and advised to use `<Object>`.

Now this is where it gets a little harder for me, because I do not know how to use the `<Object>` tag for applets. I definitely searched for answers online. Each gives different ways of declaring it for an Applet, but none of them worked. NetBeans constantly returns a warning/error messages each time I attempted different methods stated online.

So my question would be this: how do I correctly use the `<Object>` tag for a Java Applet?

After much searching, I found an example that returns no value but does not even load the Applet on my computer. The example is below:
java code:

```
<object data="VirtualArmory.jar" type="application/x-java-applet"></object>
```

I have attempted both .jar and .class and the output is still the same. The Java plugin kept loading.

**EDIT:**

This is the error I got when I used the `<Applet>` tag. But did not get any when using the `developJava.js`.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VirtualArmory
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is how I attempted the developJava.js command. Sorry since it is my first time seeing and using this command, I will tend to make a lot of mistakes.

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
var attributes = {
  codebase:'http://morganaprime.webs.com/',
    code:'VirtualArmory.class',
    archive:'VirtualArmory.jar',
    width:710, 
    height:540
};
var parameters = {gunSize:16};
var version = '1.6';
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

I am randomly attempting what ever I can to make this work! This is the link to my testing website.
[website here](http://morganaprime.webs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question would be this: how do I correctly use the `<Object>` tag for a Java Applet?

The correct answer is "don't use it" (or the `applet` element).  Instead delegate the responsibility for embedding the applet to [`deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit).  It might look something like this.

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
var attributes = {
    codebase:'http://morganaprime.webs.com/',
    code:'net.mp.eoncalculator.VirtualArmory',
    archive:'VirtualArmory.jar',
    width:710, 
    height:540
};
var parameters = {gunSize:16};
var version = '1.6';
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

> But NetBeans did state a warning message stating that the `<Applet>` tag has been deprecated..

Only since HTML 4.01 (which was a long time ago)!

### Update - working example

[image: Applet on-screen]

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
var attributes = {
    codebase:'http://morganaprime.webs.com/',
    code:'net.mp.eoncalculator.VirtualArmory',
    archive:'VirtualArmory.jar',
    width:1000,
    height:700
};
var parameters = {gunSize:16};
var version = '1.6';
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I have checked out the site on how to use the `deployJava.js`, don't really know how to use it properly. I did was a copy paste into my website and it did nothing. Will continue to attempt and research on it. And `<Applet>` tag was gone since a long time ago? That is period I stopped doing Applets!! :D

Comment: *"And `<Applet>` tag was gone since a long time ago? That is period I stopped doing Applets!!"*  No, it is more likely only recently that Netbeans has been explicitly warning about using the `applet` element.  As to the problems, what s the URL to the applet page?  I'll check it out if I get time.  BTW - make sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is visible when deploying applets.  It has vital information, and lots of it if the trace level is raised to 5.

Comment: I will update my question with the URL. Will also update my question with the error I got when I was using the `<Applet>` command. Yes, I got those errors using the Java Console.

Comment: Please let me know in a comment when you update/edit the question.  `code:'net.mp.eoncalculator.VirtualArmory',` should be the code attribute given the path within the Jar.  Obviously, the class also needs to be declared in `package net.mp.eoncalculator;`.

Comment: Wow nice! You did get my applet working nicely, but I tried your HTML code on my Webs account and it didn't work, unfortunately. Fortunately, it worked on my other website (clan forums). Which is really weird.

Comment: When I bring up the source on the page at the URL in the question now, and do a find on 'deplo' I hear.. DING - 0 hits.  Is that the page you tried to put it in?  Maybe the host does not allow custom scripts, or scripts in the body or some such.  Do you have full control of that site?

Comment: Nevermind, I resolved it. It didn't work on first attempt, and I have no idea why suddenly, first attempt, it started to work now. It is just weird. Really weird. The website, Webs, does allow Custom HTML. That is where I obviously should place these scripts. Anyway. Thank you for your hard effort of replying. Gave you the tick :)