# Fail to use Java applet in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, applet, classnotfoundexception

It's first time I have to use a Java applet and I'm failing miserably.

I was given a java applet that I need to put on ASP.NET MVC page.  I also was given a sample WebForm using the same applet.  The sample works just fine but when I put the applet on MVC page, I get an exception: ClassNotFoundException. It fails to find com.applet.SampleApplet.class. I tried to place the Sample.jar file in the root and in the View that uses the applet but no cigar so far. Here's the part that works in the sample but not in my app.

```
        <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
            width="276" height="296" align="center" 
            codebase="/supports/jre-7u1-windows-i586.exe">
        <param name="java_code" value="com.applet.SampleApplet.class">
        <param name="java_archive" value="Sample.jar">
        <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4">
        <param name="language" value="en">
        <param name="country" value="US">
        <param name="id" value="Sample">
        <param name="name" value="Sample">
        <comment>
        <EMBED type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4" 
               width="276" height="296" align="center" 
               pluginspage="/supports/jre-7u1-windows-i586.exe" 
               java_code="com.applet.SampleApplet.class">
        <param name="java_archive" value="Sample.jar">" 
               java_archive="Sample.jar" language="en" country="US" 
               id="Sample" name="Sample"/>
        <noembed>
            <p>Unable to start java plugin.</p>
        </noembed>
        </comment>
    </object>
```

Comment: 1) *"ClassNotFoundException. It fails to find com.applet.SampleApplet.class. I tried to place the Sample.jar file in the root"*  Given the class is `com.applet.SampleApplet.class` it should be in the path `com/applet` within the Jar.  The path in the Jar *must* match the package of the class.  2) Use [`deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to write the `applet` (or `object` or whatever) element that embeds `SampleApplet`. 3) See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474623/418556) for info. from you we could use

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for suggestion but when I tried it, I got exactly the same error.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you follow the course of action followed in the edit of the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14474564/418556) which was quickly resolved when I got to see the applet page, download the Jar, check the location of the class, write an example launch file (HTML/JS), test it, get the screen shot..  Do you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I finally figure out.  I need to put jar file into Content folder.  Don't understand why but it does work now.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work I needed to put the jar file into Content folder.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using net beans, make sure you have the package at the top so it knows where to look.

For example:

```
package sampleapplets;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
```